# use initial width for element not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, width

I have a graph plugin that inserts canvas and a legend `<table>` to its container. In this plugin the `table` has no `width` defined and in my CSS there is a width for tables inside that container were my plugin gets inserted.

So, the new div is inheriting `table{ width: 100%}` from the CSS and rendering wrong.

I tried to use `width: initial;`, looks good on Chrome but [**IE doesn't like it**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/initial) <sup>check browser compatibility</sup>

I admit changing/forcing a inline CSS in the script/plugin since it has to work in any enviroment.

What is the best solution here?

Comment: Have you tried just setting a minimum width? Does it work?

Comment: @BuddhistBeast, didn't think about that! But tried that now and didn't work on Chrome either.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Like you said, generally `width: auto` will have a similar effect.  Having the rules:

```
.my-selector {
    width: auto;
    width: initial;
}
```

Should cause it to use `initial` if it's supported and `auto` otherwise.

Comment: As a note, `initial` _is_ a valid property value (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial). _But_ (if you scroll down to "Browser compatibility" in the previous link), no IE version supports it.

Comment: this is known as a *fallback* and is a very common coding pattern in CSS. also, using `width: auto` will not only have a *similar* effect, but it will have the *exact same* effect, because `auto` is **defined to be the initial value** for the `width` property.

Answer (score 6):

Using `width: auto;` inline, inside the script solves the problem on Chrome, FIrefox and IE 11. Just not sure if there is a better way.