# Icon showing in Chrome & firefox but not in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Here is the CSS I pulled from IE:

```
.hglghts .active.yes-icon, .hglghts .yes-icon {
    background: url("../img/yes_sir.png") no-repeat;
    width: 27px;
    background-position: initial;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-right: -5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 17px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

It is not showing. I am using IE11.

Here is what i pulled from Chrome, same thing but this is showing?

```
.hglghts .yes-icon.active, .hglghts .yes-icon {
    background: url("../img/yes_sir.png") no-repeat;
    width: 27px;
    background-position: initial!important;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-right: -5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 17px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823105/use-initial-width-for-element-not-working-in-ie

Answer (score 0):

Problem should be in `initial` background position.

You `left top` or `0 0` instead.

```
background-position: left top;
```

Or better, in one row:

```
background: url("../img/yes_sir.png") left top no-repeat;
```

Comment: I changed it to : url("../img/yes_sir.png") left top no-repeat. Still no image?