# Round divs inside a parent round div

Tags: html, css

I would like to ask if it is possible to inserts rounded corner divs into a round div. They should be inserted in a circular way, one after another. I want to create a ring of circular divs, without changing the size of the parent div. 
Please if you know how to do it, I will really much appreciate.

Comment: You want two circles, one big and one small inside big one?

Comment: I want a big circle, and many others to create a ring inside that one. The small divs should just stay in the border of the big one. 
Or I want to create a ring made with many circular divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="one">
<div id="two"></div></div><style type="text/css">
#one{
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    background: #333;
    border-radius: 60px;
}
#two{
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 35px;
}
```

This will **work** for you. Make adjustments as your wish.
[image: White is inner, Black is outer div]

Comment: Thanks. Now I can create many divs inside the parent one and create a circular ring with them just by changing the css: 
    top: px;
    left: px; 
    right: px; etc  
Hero :)

Comment: Have you noticed that your implementation is croked?

Comment: Hey geek, this is not our homework... Look it as a template. :p

Answer (score 3):

You can define the outer element as position: relative, and inner elements with absolute. The margin will do the job to make distance between each other.

```css
.circle{
  width:256px;
  height:256px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background: rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.5);
  border:3px solid white;
  position:relative;
}

.circle >  .circle{
  width:initial;
  height:initial;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">

  <div class="circle">
  
    <div class="circle">
  
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering how to make it work under Internet Explorer, this was my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823105/use-initial-width-for-element-not-working-in-ie

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to work with fixed widths and heights it's easy enough.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div style="padding: 4px; width: 32px; height: 32px; border-radius: 20px; background-color: red;">
        <div style="padding: 4px; width: 24px; height: 24px; border-radius: 16px; background-color: orange;">
            <div style="padding: 4px; width: 16px; height: 16px; border-radius: 12px; background-color: yellow;">
                <div style="padding: 4px; width: 8px; height: 8px; border-radius: 8px; background-color: green;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Give them a padding of whatever ring thickness you want, and then each ring needs to be (padding x 2) smaller than its parent, in both width and height. Each div's border-radius needs to be half of its outer width (where outer width = width + (padding x 2)).

Example: http://doug.exploittheweb.com/SO/33677891.html

Comment: The code above creates rounded divs inside a div. I want rounded div to create a circle, like a Ring

Answer (score 0):

**First way using relative absolute divs** **https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/67/**

**HTML**

```
<div class="big-circle">
    <div class="small-circle">
        <div class="extra-small-circle">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.big-circle {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: black;
}

.small-circle {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50px, -50px);
}

.extra-small-circle {
    background: white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-25px, -25px);
}
```

**Second way using gradiant** **https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/69/**

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 17%, #ff0a0a 19%, #ff2828 40%, #000000 41%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 17%,#ff0a0a 19%,#ff2828 40%,#000000 41%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #ffffff 17%,#ff0a0a 19%,#ff2828 40%,#000000 41%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
}
```