# issue with how page is appearing on IE11

Tags: html, css, angular, internet-explorer-11

Please bear with me as I'm new to IE11 debugging.

For the info, this bug is only happening in IE11, **browsers like Chrome or FireFox do not have this issue**

Currently part of my webpage is displaying that

[image]

This is ok.

However, when choosing through a different property, and clicking on one of the property this is what I have

[image]

From what I can see, the CSS is not used/read correctly by IE11.

This is my CSS

```
        .floor-details-item {
            min-height: 160px;
            width: 100%;
            border: 0.5px solid #C2EFDF;
            border-radius: 2px; 
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            padding: 5px;

            &.opac {
                opacity: 0.2;
            }
```

I've tried to add an `!important` on the width in the css but IE11 refuses to take into account and still gives me the wrong width.

```
        .floor-details-item {
            min-height: 160px;
            width: 100% !important;
            border: 0.5px solid #C2EFDF;
            border-radius: 2px; 
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            padding: 5px;

            &.opac {
                opacity: 0.2;
            }
```

When going through IE11 console when inspecting the element, this is what I have

[image]

Funny part is when I change it manually and typing 100% as you can see below, then the width issue is fixed.

[image]

Thank you for any insight you may provide.

update :

---

I have tried the following on the CSS. As this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823105/use-initial-width-for-element-not-working-in-ie) is saying that IE 11 is not fond of width with `!important`, I added in the css the following

```
        .floor-details-item {
            min-height: 160px;
            /*width: 100% !important;*/
            /*adding auto and initial*/
            width: auto;
            width: initial;
```

But nothing so far.

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D, I'm working with IE11. My code has no issue on Chrome or FF as I said on the beginning of my question. I can give you my code but it will not help you in this occasion.

Comment: If you recreate it HERE we can open it in IE11....and inspect.

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried to carve bit of my code to show you

Comment: can you post the Enough code (include the html code and related CSS style) to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). it will be easier for us to test and help you solve it.

Comment: Hi @ZhiLv-MSFT, let me build that up. I was busy yesterday eve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many wrangles plus the help of my colleague, I found where the issue was located.

It was due to the css.

```
    .floor-details {
        width: 44%;
        margin-left: 5px;
        height: 555px;
        float: left;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
        border-left: 20px solid #C2EFDF;
        overflow-y: auto;
        padding: 5px;
        //display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;

        .floor-details-item {
            min-height: 160px;
            width: 100%;
            border: 0.5px solid #C2EFDF;
            border-radius: 2px; 
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            padding: 5px;
            //display: flex;
            min-width: 1px;
```

IE11 does not like the `display: flex;` as a child. Removing it from the child also mean removing it from the parent as you can see from the code. Once done, the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `min-width: 1px;`. It saved my ass many times;-)

Comment: Hi @johannesdz, thank you but alas, I've put the min-width in the CSS and I still have the issue. If you have any other tips, I'm all ears.

Comment: Can you comment the css from .floor-details?

Comment: what do you want me to comment?

Comment: let me do that @johannesdz

Comment: Hi @johannesdz, as you have been the only one answering my question, the points are yours. I've been able to find my issue as you can see above.